# Solflare wallet - Swap - Fraud

Tags: sol, swap, jupiter, solflare

hoping that you may give me some guidance.

1 - I wanted to buy Jupiter Coin which will come live on 31st Jan.

2 - In my solflare wallet , I had 3.9 Sol.

3 - I used SWAP option and placed my Sol tokens .

4 - From the drop down menu , I chosed Jupiter Token and pressed approve.

5 - Now , I lost all my sole and by the end of the transaction , I have  18,241.52 token something that has no value and it says the name can be false.

Is there anything I can do and apply. ? I appreciate your guidance if anyone. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are token with similar names and images. Always make sure when you swap that you are actually buying the correct token. Since Jupiter is not released yet you probably bought a token that someone else created. Make sure to not buy the ones that have a yellow exclamation mark on them.
You can try to swap back to sol, but there is no option to revert the transaction.